# Magento 2, How to get Payment infoInterface from order?

Tags: magento2, orders, payment-methods, object

I am working on a custom payment method. 
I am stuck in between where one of my methods required `Payment` object of `\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface`

But I am getting `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Interceptor`

from order object.

How Can I get this `Payment` object of `\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface`?

Thanks

Comment: Hello! Did you find the solution how to get Payment object of \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface ? I have same problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Following if your request builder is executing:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Gateway\Payment\Request;

use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Request\BuilderInterface;
use Magento\Payment\Gateway\Helper\SubjectReader;

class Yourclass implements BuilderInterface
{

    public function build(array $buildSubject)
    {
        $paymentDO = SubjectReader::readPayment($buildSubject);

       $paymentInfo = $paymentDO->getPayment()  //this will give you  \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface
    }
}
```

You refer above as example basically you need to use  $paymentDO->getPayment()  following code in your class as used in above.

Comment: Can I get this payment object by order object '$this->order->getPayment()'?

Comment: I am not using request builder

Comment: Could you share you code where you want  to  get  InfoInterface  , because as per I know if you are using magento2  pattern of building  payment gateway  you  can  get  you InfoInterface in both request and response  by using  this SubjectReader::readPayment($buildSubject)  if you  need some  where  else mention in your question.

Comment: My payment method is bit custom which is not using the magento2 Gatway.
I am trying this is controller

Comment: @Charlie have you got answer?

Comment: i get my order like this `$buildSubject['payment']->getOrder()` how would I get the quote id?

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of where an object of type `\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface` can be found and how it is instantiated.

you may want to look at the file `\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\AbstractPdf`

line `$paymentInfo = $this->_paymentData->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())->setIsSecureMode(true)->toPdf();`

this line shows you how the invoice for an order is generated. This specific line extracts the payment information for the order. And the variable `$order->getPayment()` specifically is an object of type `\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface`